# How to load data from a file upon start up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Upon startup my professor wants these instructions done,

Create a Load Event Handler to read a default file when the program starts.
    For example, expenses.txt, which you should create by hand.
Read all the expenses from the file and display them in the list box.
Calculate the total expenses and display it in the label.

I have the code that works but was wondering if there was a way to just load the data directly to the list box and totalLabel without the user selecting the expenses.txt file at start up.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Catch exceptions
    try
    {
        //Variables
        decimal total = 0m;

        StreamReader inputFile;

        //Show OpenFileDialog
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            inputFile = File.OpenText("expenses.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Convert number

                //Get file numbers
                number = decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());

                //Add expense to total
                total += number;

                displayListBox.Items.Add(number);
            }
            //Close the file
            inputFile.Close();

            //Display total
            expensesLabel.Text = total.ToString("C");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error selecting file name");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error reading file: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, there's absolutely a way to hard-code the file so it's always loaded at startup without prompting the user - but the better question is, *is that what your professor wants to happen?*  My guess is that he/she wants the option to choose his own, potentially more complicated file that tries to trip up your code.  Keep this in mind.

Comment: What's the point to use an OpenFileDialog to let the user choose a file if you always open the same file?

Comment: I wasn't able to tell by the way he worded the instructions.. I was just curious for future reference as well on how to make it automatically load without prompting the user.

Comment: Steve, that's how my professor has been making us do it.

Comment: If you use OpenFileDialog then you want to open the file choosen by the user, otherwise you can remove it and open directly the file achieving your objective to automatically load the expense file.

Comment: You wrote it already, As has been pointed out, remove the if conditional that opens the dialog box. done.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question.